# How to play a sound file

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

With C#, How do I play (Pause, Forward...) a sound file (mp3, ogg)? The file could be on the hard disk, or on the internet.

Is there any library or Class out there that can ease me the work ?

Comment: Good Question! This sort of thing is something that so many people seem to take for granted.

Comment: @ theo, I concur with you. I am actually looking for answer to similar question.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind including **Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll** in your project, you can do it this way:

```
var audio = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Audio();
audio.Play("some file path");
```

If you want to do more complex stuff, the easiest way I know of is to use the **Windows Media Player API**.  You add the DLL and then work with it.  The API is kind of clunky, but it does work; I've used it to make my own music player wrapper around Windows Media Player for personal use.  Here are some helpful links to get you started:

[Building a Web Site with ASP .NET 2.0 to Navigate Your Music Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/913360.aspx)

[Windows Media Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249259.aspx)

[Let the Music Play!](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2007/10/30/let-the-music-play-matt-gertz.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Since I wrote this, I've found an easier way, if you don't mind including WPF classes in your code.  WPF (.NET 3.0 and forward) has a [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx) class that's a wrapper around Windows Media Player.  This means you don't have to write your own wrapper, which is nice since, as I mentioned above, the WMP API is rather clunky and hard to use.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [BASS Library](http://un4seen.com/).
It can play both filebased music files and streaming content.
There is also a .NET wrapper available.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. There's even a Codeproject article on nBass ( a class wrapper of Bass). It's easy how it's done, but he do use an old version of Bass (v1.8), I'm looking for the version he used, hope I can download it.

Answer (score 2):

[Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net) has [RecordPlayer](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample1) class with these possibilities:

```
        public static void TestRecordPlayer()
        {
            RecordPlayer rp = new RecordPlayer();
            rp.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(rp_PropertyChanged);
            rp.Open(new Mp3Reader(File.OpenRead("in.mp3")));
            rp.Play();
            rp.Forward(1000);
            rp.Pause();
        }

        static void rp_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case RecordPlayer.StateProperty:
                    RecordPlayer rp = ((RecordPlayer)sender);
                    if (rp.State == DeviceState.Stopped)
                    {
                        rp.Close();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [PlaySound API call](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PlaySounds1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a media player control - basically what Media Player uses. You can put that in your program and there's an API you can use to control it. I think it's the best quick solution.