# So I want to make a basic music visualizer in C# as practice. Is there a library that lets me handle sound files easily in C#?

Tags: c#, audio

What is a sound library I can use to easily manipulate sound files (*mp3, ogg, wav, etc.*).

I'm doing this as a leasure project and as such I'm more than willing to read a bit because I want this to be a little learning experience.

Any help, SO? :D

Comment: What sort of manipulation are you planning to do? Just playing them, or actually editing them?

Comment: Sorry for the mix up. I have no intention of manipulating or otherwise editing the sound files. I just want to show bars moving to the beat, etc. Something flashy as a way to learn the GDI in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than just .wav files, as it appears you do, and you're using .NET 3.0 or higher, have a look at:

[MediaPlayer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx)

It's basically a wrapper around Windows Media Player, and will let you do in code most (if not all) of what WMP can do.

If you're still in .NET 2.0, have a look at the Windows Media Player SDK, which is a significantly uglier wrapper around Windows Media Player.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129642/how-to-play-a-sound-file/129750#129750).

Answer (score 0):

[SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(VS.80).aspx) class for wav. At the bottom of that documentation there is a link to a page explaining how to also play mp3 and wma.