# c# play sound with one line of c# code

Tags: c#, audio

I'm playing a game with some others coders.  You get to write one oneline of C# and as many xaml lines as you want.

Anyone know how to play a sound in one line before the semi-colon;

This is as close as I can get so far

```
    SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Media\pacman.wav");
    simpleSound.Play();
```

Edit:  tried Blorgbeard's code, but sound isn't playing for some reason

```
if (Listbox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2 Good 2 B True")
{
    try
    {
        (new SoundPlayer(@"/Project;component/sounds/pacman.wav")).Play();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129642/how-to-play-a-sound-file

Comment: Because...you're hoping the sound will play faster if you use less lines of code?

Comment: I'm only allowed one line of code.

Comment: Nope just some fun at work.  It seems to be turning out to like a Monty Python animation.

Comment: with work like that, who needs play?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need for a variable:

```
(new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Media\pacman.wav")).Play();
```

Comment: I'm sure it works but I'm still not hearing anything.  No errors either.  see edit above with code.

Comment: @rd42 Does it work if you do it in two lines with the same filename?

Comment: @Rd42 are you sure your speakers are turned on?

Comment: It was my path.  When I hard coded the path c:\blah blah blah it works, but the /Project;component/sounds/pacman.wav doesn't.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Blorgbeard's code works for me if I use PlaySync() instead of Play():

```
(new SoundPlayer(soundFile)).PlaySync();
```

Play() plays sound in another thread. This may be the issue.