# how to generate voice with C# without tts (Speech synthesis)?

Tags: voice

Is it possible to create voice with C# without using tts (Speech synthesis)? I tried all kinds of things and i could just make a beep sound. i need an example of generate a single letter or word.

Comment: Generating a single letter or word *is* speech synthesis. Strictly speaking, not every speech synthesis has to be tts (text-to-speech), but once you can generate single letters, it is more often than not the most straightforward way of parametrization that you get the information what letters to concatenate as some form of text, thus ending up with a text-to-speech system.

Comment: TTS does not exist in my language so I can not use it and I need to create some things alone. I need a letter or a word just for example.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here: TTS is not a particular product that can exist for a given language, it is a generic concept that undoubtedly does exist, even if it may not have been implemented for a particular language. As such, the question "How do I generate voice without text-to-speech?" does not make much sense, because generating voice is more or less synonymous to *doing* text-to-speech. I suggest changing your title to "How to generate voice without a third-party text-to-speech engine?"

Answer (score 1):

You can only play sounds if you have a pre-recorded source. See this link: [c# play sound with one line of c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756855/c-sharp-play-sound-with-one-line-of-c-sharp-code)

If you need to play speech sound from dynamic text, then you have no option but use one of TTS libraries.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I do not want to use TTS And use the recordings files it's not an option for me.

Comment: You better correct your question then. "I tried all kinds of things and i could just make a beep sound." implies that you don't know how to play sound in C#.

Comment: TTS does not exist in my language so I can not use it and I need to create some things alone. I need a letter or a word just for example.

Comment: Use Google Speech engine if it can speak your language. If not you can try other sound reach languages by using translit, so they sound like the word you need in your language. Google Speech engine allows to download sound to your machine after it is generated on Google's servers.

Comment: Google does not support my language, and make it heard in my language that does not sound good at all. I need to record 300 words every day for a month and every day it sounds a little different and it does not sound good at all (because I have to play it randomly). I tried everything except creating my own voice with code like TTS.

Comment: May I ask, what is your language?

Comment: my language is hebrew

Comment: First off thanks for all the help. Yes it does not work.