# How can I play any audio file(e.g. mp3,wav) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question regarding with audio files.My question is:How can I play any audio file(e.g. mp3,wav) in C#? So if I press a button,I want to play to an audio file.
How can I do that? Can you tell me how it is done with a sample code?Lastly,I have used .Net Framework 4.0.

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried so far ? what is not working ?

Comment: possible duplicate [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129642/how-to-play-a-sound-file)

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far.Just I want to learn how it is done?

Comment: @Selo: It's done by NAudio, the C# wave audio library, for example. Did you looked up for any, using google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for that first you need to load wmp.dll from your system32 folder
2. Then you need to add COM component
3. Now you can do other things(creating player)

Answer (score 0):

I have a tiny project (cutted NAudio version, only playback is left and only MP3 and WAV is supported) to play MP3 and WAV files. Do you still need it? I can upload it if you need to.

Comment: First of all ,thanks for your help.As you mentioned,I need sample project.

Comment: You will get a link to download sample c# player, if you ask that in another question. Anyway, my proposal seems to be not correct.

Answer (score 0):

A full code example on how to play waves in c# forms apps can be found here

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173187%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
```

You can also play wave files using C# and the XNA Framework. But that may not serve your purpose, since that is primarily for games development.

Comment: To play MP3 in C# you steel need to decode programmatically (using FFT or other algorighm, used by mp3, ogg format) or using you video/accelerator card (please, do not laugh ;|, ATI and NVIDIA SDKs already is up to date)