# Creating audio visualizer using libvlc

Tags: c#, wpf, libvlc

I am trying to create a audio wave visualizer using libvlc. Have searched the net thoroughly but was unable to find any help. It would be really great if anyonce can help me out here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that reading [random questions with the tags C# and libvlc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+libvlc) may already help you to understand how libvlc works.

Comment: I have been able to play videos using libvlc. But what I am looking for is some fft function to create a wave like audio visualizer.havent found it yet. Any suggestions will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I now see what you're trying to achieve :) There isn't such a thing built in libvlc (or it's hidden very well). I fear that you will have to craft something based on the audio callbacks to get audio information from the media player and do whatever you can with, but I doubt you will find any high-level function for that :/

Comment: I have found this link https://github.com/vlcchina/vlc-player-dev/blob/master/modules/visualization/visual/fft.c ..it seems there are fft functions..but havent found it in my vlc and really not getting any help on using it in code

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can get waveform with the help of *Stream to memory* module (smem)

https://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_to_memory_(smem)_tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `MediaPlayer` Class.

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx

It is a wrapper around Windows Media Player which will let you do in code most of what WMP can do.

If you are using .NET 2.0 you will have to look at `Windows Media Player SDK`.

In that case, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129642/how-to-play-a-sound-file/129750#129750) might be helpful for you.

Comment: I am using vlc library that's libvlc.

Comment: why you taged it under libvlc